# joining three select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I create reports in SQL Server Report Builder. I hope anyone can help me in this case. My query shows me an error if I add a third inner join

How can I add a third select statement?

Comment: FYI, just coloring a bunch of unformatted text as `code` doesn't make it readable

Comment: Add `Name` to the group by in the third query (`E`).   Move the first ON condition to before the second JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the final [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause. Including the full name in the [SELECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx) clause requires the full name in the GROUP BY.

As a rule of thumb:  When using GROUP BY every field used in the SELECT clause, that isn't combined with an [aggregate function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173454.aspx), must appear.

```
Select 
    SUM(cast(Units as int)) as CounterName, 
    left(Name,4) as Machine, 
    Name as WasteLabel 
from 
    Trouble 
        inner join tsystem ON Trouble.systemid = tsystem.id
where 
    Name not in ('Aus', 'An', 'Produced')
    and IntervalDateWeek >=  dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()) - 2, 0)  
    and IntervalDateWeek <= dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate())-1, 0)
    and left(Name, 4) in (Select name from tSystem
where 
    ID in 
        (
            Select 
                systemid 
            from 
                tsystemviewSystemwhere 
            WHERE
                SystemViewID = 4)
        )
group by 
    Name
```

I suspect your query could be improved.  Adding [clear sample data and expected output](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help here.

Comment: thank you for your help. and sorry for my bad english, thats why I cannot explain my problem :)